# How do I use the apollo-server default resolver with a function?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

In the default resolvers section of the Graphql-tools documentation, it states

> 1. Returns a property from obj with the relevant field name, or
> 2. **Calls a function on obj with the relevant field name and passes the query arguments into that function**

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers.html#Default-resolver

Type defs:

```
type AggregateMessage {
  count: Int!
}
```

Given this query resolver:

```
Query: {
    async messagesConnection(root: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) {
      const messages: IMessageDocument[] = await messageController.messages();

      const edges: MessageEdge[] = [];
      for (const node of messages) {
        edges.push({
          node: node,
          cursor: node.id
        });
      }
      // return messages;
      return {
        pageInfo: {
            hasNextPage: false,
            hasPreviousPage: false
        },
        edges: edges,
        aggregate: {
          count: () => {
            // Resolve count only
            return 123;
          }
        }
      };
   }
}
```

So if I manually define the resolver like this it works.

```
AggregateMessage: {
    count(parent: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) {
      return parent.count();
      // Default resolver normally returns parent.count
      // I want it to return parent.count() by default
    }
}
```

But if I remove the definition and rely on default resolving functionality it does not work.

I expect it to call the function parent.count() as per point #2 in the documentation if I remove the manual resolver and rely on the default resolver behavior to call the function on the property name.

> 2. Calls a function on obj with the relevant field name and passes the
>      query arguments into that function

However it gives a type error because "count" is defined as an Int type but it's actually a function. How can I do this correctly so the count function is called and the value returned when resolving, without having to define the resolver myself?

`Int cannot represent non-integer value: [function count]`

Comment: @Egor did you mean to link something else?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that) its actual link https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations

Comment: There's no reason the above code shouldn't work. I can run it locally just fine as plain js, so I suspect it's a typescript issue. It would be helpful to include the error you're seeing, including the trace, otherwise it's difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: May also be helpful to see your definition for AggregateMessage. I suspect you've got `count` defined as `number` as opposed to `number | () => number`

Comment: Typescript is not throwing the error. The error shows up when I query apollo-server (code compiles and runs). I'm using graphql SDL, so not sure how to define the type it can return as a function. I'm specifically trying to rely on the apollo-server default resolver functionality. So if I define the AggregateMessage resolver as shown, then it works, but if I remove the AggregateMessage resolver it does not work if count is a function, but it does work if count returns a number.

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/intelligent-buckaroo so I made this to test it and it indeed works. I matched the apollo-server and graphql versions and for some reason my server still gives the error. Will have to slowly remove things to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turns out to be caused by mergeSchemas from graphql-tools.

When passing resolvers to mergeSchemas (instead of to apollo-server or to makeExecutableSchema), the default resolver functionality for functions does not work properly.

https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/1061

I'm not sure if this is intended functionality, but moving the resolvers to the makeExecutableSchema call fixed the issue.